# Anyway to lock a @Produces method

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

I have a Singleton EJB with a Producer method.

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class MyBean{

    private Something something;

    @Produces
    public MySomething getSomething() {              
          if(null == something){
               LOG.info("Initializing MySomething.");
               something = new Something();
          }
          return something;
    }
}
```

I assumed this would lock but I'm seeing this `"Initializing MySomething."` in the logs multiple times then Something throws a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

So looks like I need to lock this `@Produces` method.

Is it ok  to use a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you really want is this:

```
@Produces @ApplicationScoped
public MySomething getSomething()  {
    // ....
}
```

Since your producer method does not have an explicit scope, it defaults to `@Dependent` scope, so a new bean instance gets created for every injection point. That's why you're getting multiple log messages.

Comment: I believe this is what I want. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to create `Something` in your post construct, and simply return that.  EJB Singletons are meant to be a single instance per app

```
public class MyBean {
    private Something something;
    @PostConstruct
    public void createSomething() {
        this.something = new Something();
    }
    @Produces
    public Something getSomething() {
        return this.something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. But couldn't you just annotate the field directly? Why the extra getter?

Comment: You can.  I've always found method producers to be cleaner to read.